# How to add an existing folder to a VS project which might contain some dlls of same name?

Tags: c#

I have written an application(C# project) which i want it to be launched through website (clickonce application).
I want to add an existing folder which contains some dlls, xml files. 
It has its own folder structure. I want to add this folder to my project.
Problem is, few dlls which this folder contains are also present in my project and its under references. Both dlls are of different version so I have to add that folder..
Can you please let me know a way to add an existing folder to a project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

Mutliple versions of the same class library may be stored in the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), a special folder; but within a project, you're working with a standard file system, which can't contain multiple files with identical names side by side (even if of different casing, when on Windows.)

You *could* probably get away with storing them in a Solution Folder (one maintained within the solution itself, not physically, but a virtual folder) and have files stored in there from *different* physical locations, but I've never played with this to be certain how well it would pan out. Also, it could just mount confusion, so I'd steer blear, personally.